# Is there a proof of the real form of Fourier's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, alternative-proof

## Complex form of Fourier's Theorem

Any periodic function can be decomposed into a linear combination of complex exponentials.

## Proof

Consider a complex exponential with period $T_0$:
$$e^{i\frac {2π}{T_0}t}$$
Hence, we have:
$$\int^{T_0}_0 e^{i\frac {2π}{T_0}t} dt = 0 ……(1)$$
Let us claim that for a periodic function $x(t)$ we can write:
$$x(t) ≈ \sum^{N}_{k=-N} C_ke^{i\frac {2πk}{T_0}t},$$
where $2N+1$ is the number of frequency components used. As $N→∞$, we have:
$$x(t) = \sum^{∞}_{k=-∞} C_ke^{i\frac {2πk}{T_0}t} ……(2)$$
Consider:
$$v_k(t):=e^{i\frac {2πk}{T_0}t}……(3)$$
Then we have:
$$v_k(t+T_0)=v_k(t)$$
Hence, $v_k(t)$ is a periodic function. Now,
$$\int^{T_0}_0 v_k(t)v^*_l(t) dt$$
$$=\int^{T_0}_0 e^{i\frac {2π(k-l)}{T_0}t} dt$$
$$=0 (k≠l)$$
$$T_0 (k=l)……(4)$$
Thus, $v_k(t)$ is orthogonal. Moreover, if we assume equation (2) to be valid , then we can multiply both its sides by $v_l^*(t)$ and integrate over $T_0$ we get:
$$C_k=\frac {1}{T_0} \int^{T_0}_0 x(t)v_k^*(t) dt ……(5)$$
Putting this value in equation (2) we get back $x(t)$.
Hence, any periodic function can be decomposed into a linear combination of complex exponentials.

## Real form of Fourier's Theorem

An arbitrary periodic function $F(t)$ with period $T$ can be decomposed into a linear combination of the functions $f_n(t)$ and $g_n(t)$ where,
$$f_n(t)=\sin \frac {2πnt}{T}$$
$$g_n(t)=\cos \frac {2πnt}{T}$$
Mathematically,
$$F(t)=b_0 + b_1g_1(t) +b_2g_2(t) + …… + a_1f_1(t) +a_2f_2(t) + ……,$$
where $n$ is a non-negative integer and all of $a_i$,$b_i$ are real.

## Problem

Is there a similar proof for the real form of Fourier's Theorem as for the complex form? I couldn't get one on the internet or in any book. Does this mean that it can be derived from the complex form? If yes then how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you take a real-valued function, your Fourier coefficients satisfy $C_{-k}=\overline{C_k}$. Then the terms involving $C_k$  and $C_{-k}$ combine to give real-valued combinations of sines and cosines.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you express $c_n e^{2i \pi n t/T} +\overline{c_n} e^{-2i \pi n t/T}$ in term of $\cos,\sin$ ? (hint $c_n = u_n+iv_n, \overline{c_n} = u_n-iv_n$)

Comment: It's definitely worth noting that your proof of the complex case is incorrect - you establish that *if* such an expansion exists, then the coefficients $C_k$ are what you say they are. You do not prove that the proposed expansion of $x(t)$ as a sum of complex exponentials actually equals $x(t)$ - more directly, equation (2) is the thing you're trying to prove and you've assumed it instead! It'd be worth correcting your proof - there's a lot of insight to gain in the missing step that could easily answer your question about the real case too.

Comment: @Milo Brandt, I agree with you , the site from where I picked up the proof does say nothing about that step , it seems that the proof is not a proof rather a justification, I would be obliged if you could get me an actual proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions
$$
   1,\sin(2\pi x/T),\cos(2\pi x/T),\sin(4\pi x/T),\cos(4\pi x/T),\cdots
$$
are mutually orthogonal. That is, if you choose any two different functions $f,g$ from the above, then
$$
        \int_{-T}^{T} f(x)g(x)dx = 0.
$$
And,
$$
    \int_{-T}^{T}1^2dx=2T\\ \int_{-T}^{T}\sin^2(2\pi x/T)dx=T\\ \int_{-T}^{T}\cos^2(2\pi x/T)dx=T.
$$
That's enough to carry about the same argument that you used before. It should be noted that your argument *assumes* convergence of the series, and does not prove it.